# Vue 3 modal with transition and v-if

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have the following code that renders a modal

```
<button @click="openEditUserModal(user.id)">Open Modal</button>

<EditUserModal :key="`EditUserModal-${selectedUser.id}`" :user="selectedUser" :opened="modalIsShowing"/>

<script>
const modalIsShowing = ref(false)
const users = ref<Array<User>>([])
const selectedUser = ref<User>()

const openEditUserModal = (userId) => {
    selectedUser.value = users.value.find(user => user.id === userId)
    modalIsShowing.value = true
}

onMounted(async () => {
    const { data: usersData } = await axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:3001/users')
    users.value = usersData.users
})
```

This is the modal content (simplified, showing only the props)

```
<script setup lang="ts">

const props = defineProps({
    opened: {
        type: Boolean
    },
    user: {
        type: Object as PropType<User>,
        required: true
    }
})
```

I'm getting an error saying `Type User | undefined is not assignable to type User`
Now the solution I was thinking of, and I know is wrong, was to add `v-if="selectedUser"` to the element, making it look like this: **Because of the use of v-if, this causes the modal to not animate open.**

```
<EditUserModal v-if="selectedUser" :key="EditUserDrawer-12" :user="selectedUser" :opened="modalIsShowing"/>
```

**Is there a method in Vue 3 that allows me to not send undefined to this modal, without having to use v-if?**

Comment: can you provide more about `selectedUser`? How is it set, is it computed/prop?

Comment: I think it's fine that user might be undefined, as long as being undefined doesn't cause any errors.  so the problem is just making typescript aware of the proper types involved. 
variable types must match exactly when assigning, so you could either always initialize selectedUser as empty User object removing the possibility that it's ever undefined OR define the prop user type `Object as PropType<User | undefined>` which will allow undefined type during assignment

Comment: @yoduh so you would handle the undefined in the modal itself? It's an "edit user" modal, so I'm not sure if it should be shown at all when there's no user, however as soon as the axios request works there will always be a user.

Comment: @depperm I added more code, thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't use `v-if` you will get `undefined` sent to it, so there's not much you can do from the parent, so instead the child should accept `undefined`

```js
    user: {
        type: Object as PropType<User>,
        required: false
    }
```

You will need to change how the modal handles not having user defined

Personally, I would implement it using the explicit `null`, as suggested by [docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/composition-api.html#typing-template-refs)

```js
    user: {
        type: Object as PropType<User | null>,
        required: true
    }

// and 

const selectedUser = ref<User | null>(null)
```

Comment: The thing is what would a modal do if it doesn't yet have the data that it needs to be shown, although in most cases if there's no data it means there's an error somewhere higher up the page. So I'll just not show the modal from inside the modal. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: It wouldn't show up, that's why `v-if` is usually used but If you want to avoid using it. You could also look into fixing the animation so that you can use `v-if`

Comment: Yes. I’m going to give it a class that hides it using css, when user is undefined. So that when it is defined, it pops up. Thanks!